# Replacement for ability to "send tab to remote device" as removed from Firefox 29

Tags: sync, share-menu, intents

Firefox 29 [removed](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/29.0/releasenotes/) the ability to "send tab to remote device".
Namely, you could send a share intent from any other app (select "share", select "Firefox", select any other Firefox Sync device you want to send the tab to) and a few seconds to minutes later it would appear e.g. in your desktop Firefox as a new tab.

That was my main use of Firefox on Android. How do I get exactly that back?

That is, I want send tabs *from* an Android share intent *to* Firefox on the desktop! *Not* the other way (I do have FoxToPhone, but hardly ever use it).
It should be a one-click operation, I don't want to copy/paste URLs, I don't even need a target device selection (although I would be okay with the two-click operation required in Firefox 28), because I always want to send to the same device.

This should work even when the Android device is offline (plane), in which case the tabs should simply be queued and sent when the network comes back (that's exactly what Firefox 28 did).

The use case is everything I spot on mobile (from emails, interesting stuff while browsing, reading articles on Pocket, etc.) but that maybe doesn't work on mobile (Flash), requires more screen estate or just requires some kind of action from me, which I don't want to perform on mobile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Mozilla Firefox release notes, they have completely removed the "Send tab to remote device" feature.

You can use Pushbullet. It's an Android app that helps you to view Android notifications on the PC. And you can also push files, pages, URLs from the Android app to the PC.

**TODO:**
1. Install the [Pushbullet App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android) on your phone.
2. Install the [Pushbullet extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pushbullet/chlffgpmiacpedhhbkiomidkjlcfhogd?hl=en) in your browser (supports Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for! And Pushbullet actually supports Firefox, too! (I submitted an edit to your answer to clarify that.)

Comment: Offline functionality isn't perfect. There's a notification with an error message appearing which you have to keep around and then manually trigger a retry when network is back. You can't remove the notification, or the push will be lost. But I love some of the other features.

Comment: I'm not aware that Pushbullet also supports Mozilla. Because I used it in chrome. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for the trouble this is causing you. We initially removed the feature because we didn't know how well it was being used and the UX around it seemed confusing. We intended to improve the feature and release it again soon.

That said, with feedback like yours, and many others, we are reconsidering the decision and will try to get a version of the feature back in Firefox as soon as possible.

You can track some of the discussion here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1002628

Comment: Thanks for commenting here. I have to second what Tom Lowenthal said there: it's never end user-friendly to remove a feature 'temporarily', which you anyway intend to bring back. If you don't plan to get rid of the feature in the long term, then don't 'disable' it, fix it first.

Comment: Besides, I wish you were linking to your Bugzilla bugs in your release notes. I also spent an hour or two today, trying to figure out what happened to this, and I couldn't find the issue for one reason or another. That would certainly also help: to communicate the changes you're making, rather than just having a "oh, we removed X. good luck!" line in your release notes.

Comment: If it's removed, why does my Firefox for Android still have the little paper airplane I can share to, still pop up my computer name, and still say "Your tab was sent!" when I send it? But it never shows up. Both my firefoxes are up to date. It didn't stop working till I enabled the new Firefox Sync.

Comment: @Noumenon Firefox restored the feature and it's working again for me. Your issue seems unrelated to the (temporary) removal of the feature in Firefox 29, so you should probably open a separate question with more information on the specific issue you are having.

Comment: @hheimbuerger Opened the new question at http://superuser.com/questions/965773/firefox-for-android-send-to-device-stopped-arriving-at-firefox-on-my-laptop